# Rename files in Laravel's public folder

Tags: php, laravel

I have this structure in my public folder:

```
/images
    /player_icons
        Ajax.png
        Barcelona.png
        ...
```

I need to let the admin user rename a file simply by entering a new name, rather than uploading a new file.

I have tried the old school PHP way:

```
rename('/images/player_icons/Ajax.png', '/images/player_icons/test.png');
```

This produces the error:

```
File not found at path: images/player_icons/Ajax.png
```

I have also tried using the `Storage` facade, although from the looks of it, this can't work in the public folder:

```
Storage::move('/images/player_icons/Ajax.png', '/images/player_icons/test.png');
```

I don't understand why the `rename()` option doesn't work. If I visit `example.com/images/player_icons/Ajax.png` in the browser, the image is there.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: I would try doing that by using the full path from /var/www

Comment: I can't use the absolute path, this needs to work across multiple environments.

Comment: Sure you can... use dirname(__FILE__) (two underlines before and after FILE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may need to give the [`public_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-public-path) helper function a try

> The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the
>   public directory. You may also use the public_path function to
>   generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the public
>   directory

However, renaming things on the public directory directly means that you **HAVE** to give this directory a write permissions or change the ownership for this directory to be owned by the server user ( which is almost will be `www-data` )
this is kind of a risky thing.

The better approach is to ( symlink ) the storage path ( which is writable by default ) and let the user upload and rename files there

more about this will be found here : [File system docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
rename(public_path('/images/player_icons/Ajax.png'), public_path('/images/player_icons/test.png'));
```